# Llamar funcion desde un fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment

estoy tratando de llamar la funsion saveNameToLocalStorage para guardar datos a sqlite, pero al tratar de llamarla me indica que hacen falta parametros

este es el error que me da:

```
...\basicactivity\SecondFragment.java:91: error: method saveNameToLocalStorage in class SecondFragment cannot be applied to given types;
                saveNameToLocalStorage();
                ^
  required: String,int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Este es el código de mi función saveNameToLocalStorage

```
private void saveNameToLocalStorage(String name, int status) {
    editTextName.setText("");
    db.addName(name, status);
    Name n = new Name(name, status);
    names.add(n);
    refreshlist();
}
```

y este es el codigo de mi fragment:

```
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    registerReceiver(new NetworkStateChecker(), new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

    db= new DatabaseHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    names = new ArrayList<>();

    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent){
            loadNames();
        }
    };
    registerReceiver (broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DATA_SAVED_BRODCAST));

    binding.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            saveNameToLocalStorage();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas llamando de esta forma el método:

saveNameToLocalStorage();

pero obtienes el error:

> error: method saveNameToLocalStorage in class SecondFragment cannot be
> applied to given types;
> saveNameToLocalStorage();

**el problema indica que el método esta definido para recibir 2 parametros un `String` y un `int` los cuales no los estas definiendo.**

```
private void saveNameToLocalStorage(String name, int status) {
    editTextName.setText("");
    db.addName(name, status);
    Name n = new Name(name, status);
    names.add(n);
    refreshlist();
}
```

Debes enviar los parámetros que defines para el método, por ejemplo:

```
 saveNameToLocalStorage("Ferney Guerrero", 109);
```